# Javascript not executed in Jupyter cell after if condition

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I would like to execute some Javascript code in a jupyter cell based on some condition.

This works:

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
Javascript("alert('Works')")
```

This fails

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
my_bool = True
if my_bool:
    Javascript("alert('Fails')")
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Just found a solution. But if you have a more elegant way, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to do it: inject the python boolean variable into a string executed by JavaScript

```
Javascript("if (" + str.lower(str(my_bool)) + ") { alert('Works');}")
```